# Google oAuth v2 - user profile - country parameter missing

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I would like to get the user's country info as specified in the documentation [1]. I tried using the Google API explorer and the samples, and still cant get the country info. I even tried updated the test account's profile info.

[1] https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login

[2] https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/oauth2/v2/oauth2.userinfo.get?_h=15&

The field editor in the Google API does not list parameter for *country* either. Is there some undocumented way that anyone knows about. Assuming that the user would provide complete access for their profile to the client app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid that the documentation is inconsistent.

In the description of the userinfo.profile scope we do list "country" as part of the basic profile information being authorized by the user. However, and as described later in the documentation, locale information is provided instead.

The documentation will be updated shortly in order to avoid further confusion.